# Strange character at appendix numbering

Tags: numbering, chapters, greek, appendix

I am writing my thesis in latex and added an appendix at the end of the document. The language of the document is in greek by:

```
\usepackage[english, greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

As such, the appendix chapter numbering is in greek numeral: Α,Β,Γ,Ε,... and so forth.

The problem lies with number six: in greek numerals it is ΣΤ but in latex I get this strange character:

### [image: Strange character for number six as a greek numerals, appendix chapter numbering]

In order to generate the appendix I used the following format:

```
  /appendix
  /chapter{chapter 1}
    chapter 1 contents
  /chapter{chapter 2}
    chapter 2 contents
  ...
/end{document}
```

I searched everywhere but it seems noone else has encountered this problem so far. Is there anything I can do to fix this? A possible way is to number this particular chapter with something else, so I tried:

```
$\Sigma T$
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `greek.ldf` file uses `\textstigma` and `\textStigma` for the alphabetic representation of the number six, which output as

[image]

As far as I know, the glyphs are only used in this context, so a cheap way to get

[image]

is to change the meaning of the commands mentioned above.

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}

\renewcommand{\textstigma}{\textsigma\texttau}
\renewcommand{\textStigma}{\textSigma\textTau}

\newcounter{test}
\renewcommand{\thetest}{\Alph{test}}

\begin{document}

\appendix
\setcounter{chapter}{5}

\chapter{ABG}

\stepcounter{test}\thetest\quad
\stepcounter{test}\thetest\quad
\stepcounter{test}\thetest\quad
\stepcounter{test}\thetest\quad
\stepcounter{test}\thetest\quad
\stepcounter{test}\thetest

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to keep the meaning of `\textstigma` and `\textStigma`, while changing the alphabetic representation of numbers, you can patch the relevant macro:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\gr@num@i}{\textstigma}{\textsigma\texttau}{}{}
\makeatother

\newcounter{test}
\renewcommand{\thetest}{\Alph{test}}

\begin{document}

\appendix
\setcounter{chapter}{5}

\chapter{ABG}

\stepcounter{test}\thetest\quad
\stepcounter{test}\thetest\quad
\stepcounter{test}\thetest\quad
\stepcounter{test}\thetest\quad
\stepcounter{test}\thetest\quad
\stepcounter{test}\thetest

\end{document}
```

Note that `utf8x` is unmaintained and the standard `utf8` option is default in recent LaTeX distributions, perfectly covering Greek.

Comment: Both solutions wokred, thanx!